# How does StanfordNLP / CoreNLP handle ambigue sentence structures?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNLP to parse my sentences and it works surprisingly good. But I am wondering: Since CoreNLP contains a probabilistic parser, how does the software deal with ambiguities?

"I saw the girl with the glasses".

(1) If I understand it the right way, CoreNLP prints the MOST probably tree. So there is no way to check, if there is a ambiguity, right? 
(2) Does that actually mean, that CoreNLP ignores syntactical ambiguities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CoreNLP will pick one of the two interpretations and return that. Though, it's important to note that the "most probable tree" is the one that's *syntactically* most probable (i.e., most like trees its seen in the training data), rather than most probable based on any sort of real-world knowledge. Chances are, "I ate the cake with a cherry" and "I ate the cake with a fork" will have the same parse.